# Not able to open a URL using WATIJ

Tags: java, watij

I just started with WATIJ. I am not able to open a URL in Mozilla. Using this code:

```
WebSpec spec = new WebSpec().mozilla();
```

I get the exception:

> Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Please post entire stacktrace.

Comment: The issue was with the jre. I got it resolved. Thanks alot

Comment: Consider posting an answer describing the solution in case other people might have the same problem. You will be able to accept you own answer, cf. [Should I not answer my own questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions).